# How the architecture should be for a Java command line app integrating with shopify

Tags: java, shopify

In my company we have a custom point of sale which was built in house, and I am assigned to integrate the POS with the shopify. For the mvp, we have decided to go with the simple java app, which will run from the command line. I have done the following
1) Went to `www.shopify.com/app-developers` and then got my private store `bla.myshopify.com`. 
 2) Then went to Apps -> private apps. Got my API key, password and shared secret.
 As I have mentioned, we are doing a simple java app which can run from command line. This app will read all the keys from the local file. **Now should I be doing OAUTH?** As they have mentioned to redirect to a web page in here `https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth`. Since we have don't have a webpage, where should I redirect the user to?

And is there anything wrong I am doing? Kindly correct me if there is a better architecture

Comment: you only need a private app, not oauth

Comment: Basic Authentication works with Shopify:
Whatever package you are using for your http connection should have tools to let you set the Authorization header.
Look up pre-emptive authorization for your package and use the API Key:Password for the Base 64 encrypted credential token

Answer (score 0):

Basic Authentication works with Shopify: Whatever package you are using for your http connection should have tools to let you set the Authorization header. Look up pre-emptive authorization for your package and use the API Key:Password (from the private app) for the Base 64 encrypted credential token